# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in react render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote this component and I need to pull the followers array length to display how many followers each user has in his profile. fetchUser() calls a backend API . I use Redux and Reselect.

```
import MessageList from "../containers/MessageList";
import UserAside from "./UserAside";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUser } from "../store/actions/users";
import { selectFetching,selectUserToCheckProfile } from '../store/selectors'
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";

class Profile extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const { fetchUser } = this.props;
        fetchUser(this.props.match.params.userId)
    }
    render() {
        const {fetching,userToCheckProfile}=this.props
        console.log(userToCheckProfile)
       const followers=userToCheckProfile.followers.length
     

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <MessageList userToVisit={this.props.match.params.userId} {...this.props} />
               {
                   !fetching? <UserAside
                   {...this.props}  userToCheckProfile={userToCheckProfile}
               />:'waiting.....'
               }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps=state=>createStructuredSelector({
    fetching:selectFetching,
    userToCheckProfile: selectUserToCheckProfile

})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchUser: (id) => dispatch(fetchUser(id))
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
```

I get this error!
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

this is my object in the console !

also,  userToCheckProfile.messages.length , userToCheckProfile.messages[0]  produce the same error!

```
{messages: Array(1), followers: Array(0), _id: "5f89b7e4f877294944d8d706", email: "kanye@kanye.com", username: "kanye", …}
email: "kanye@kanye.com"
followers: []
messages: ["5f89b856f877294944d8d707"]
password: "$2b$10$jSP28GIBMWirGuMBf4sp/eTBXgsT3MgRT/yfoxQBN9o69aPeDUeie"
profileImageUrl: ""
username: "kanye"
__v: 1
_id: "5f89b7e4f877294944d8d706"
__proto__: Object}
```

Comment: because the followers is emptyl 'followers: []'

Comment: What do you get if you log only userToCheckProfile.followers?

Comment: Try this because followers is still undefined?: const followers = userToCheckProfile && userToCheckProfile.followers? userToCheckProfile.followers.length:null

Comment: @ÁdámMaul I get an empty Array

Comment: That error message means that followers is undefined. Like @charly1212 wrote, you could just check if followers is defined and it has a length property like this: if(userToCheckProfile.followers && userToCheckProfile.followers) if this gives true then you can use .length, if its not, set const followers to 0.

Comment: @charly1212 yes this worked, However I'm still confused as far as the chronological order of things

Comment: @amine-chatteli well you have to keep in mind, the render() method will be called basically every time any prop or state changes. You have to make sure state and prop are defined when that happens.

Comment: Simple, use destructure and add default values `const { fetching, userToCheckProfile = { followers: [] }} = this.props`

Comment: I see where I messed up, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
import MessageList from "../containers/MessageList";
import UserAside from "./UserAside";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUser } from "../store/actions/users";
import { selectFetching,selectUserToCheckProfile } from '../store/selectors'
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";

class Profile extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const { fetchUser } = this.props;
        fetchUser(this.props.match.params.userId)
    }
    render() {
        const {fetching,userToCheckProfile}=this.props
        console.log(userToCheckProfile)
        const followers=(userToCheckProfile && userToCheckProfile.followers && userToCheckProfile.followers.length) || 0;
     

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <MessageList userToVisit={this.props.match.params.userId} {...this.props} />
               {
                   !fetching? <UserAside
                   {...this.props}  userToCheckProfile={userToCheckProfile}
               />:'waiting.....'
               }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps=state=>createStructuredSelector({
    fetching:selectFetching,
    userToCheckProfile: selectUserToCheckProfile

})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchUser: (id) => dispatch(fetchUser(id))
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
```